# Java Generic Class Exclude Collections from Type Parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I've found a proper way to implement the logic I was looking for, but I'm curious as to why the following doesn't work. Half an hour searching yielded no answers but it is possible I'm not wording the question properly.

What I wanted to do was limit the type parameter such that Collections would not be accepted. While I can test the parameter type, I'd rather have the IDE indicate that the Class doesn't accept a Collection as a type parameter. I'm aware that the keyword excludes doesn't exist but I hope it helps illustrate the question at hand.

```
public class Foo<K excludes Collection, V>
{
  //TODO: Carry out Collectionist operations
}
```

Is there any way to do this in Java? I presume this isn't a best practice, even if it is possible, but I'd like to satiate my curiosity in an effort to expand my understanding of Generics.

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: You should bound K to whatever Foo does accept, and anything else would be excluded implicitly.

Comment: What does it accept? What types do you want it to accept?

Comment: It would be an extensive list (String & all the wrapper classes). No collections, sets, or other data structures. <K extends String & Integer & Double & Character....> is a little verbose, but this would achieve my desired result I think.

Comment: Well, they all must have a single parent, upon which all the methods you use in your class will work, or else your code won't work at all. It sounds like you may need to rethink your design in general. If you provide us with more information on what you are trying to do, perhaps we can give you some advise.

Comment: I redesigned and implemented it properly, but my initial goal was to generate objects with a parameter, typed such that *edit* the parameter *edit* did not implement the Collection interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excluding certain types is not possible. Due to the way how Java types interfaces, I could simply roll up my own `Collection` that has the exact same operations, and it would not be excluded.

Just for the sake of curiosity it is a fair question, I am not aware of a way of achieving it at compile time though. You can place a runtime check in `Foo`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to implement like that.

The current version of generics only supports extends or super. It does not support any negative scenario like that.